# Download/Save/Write a file on the client's hard disk using flash/flex

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, download

I wonder how can I download/save/write a file from **my server** to a **client's computer** using flash or flex.

> An example of what I'm looking for is
>   avilable on
>   http://www.flexdownloads.com
>
> 1. Sign up
> 2. Sign in
> 3. Click on the ("FREE") button placed on the right of the page. (the
>      orange button)
> 4. Choose any product (won't cost you anything)
> 5. Press "BUY NOW"
>
> then you'll see a confirmation popup
>   for the download, then you choose
>   where do you want to save the file,
>   and the flash movie saves the file!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use FileReference**

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=17_Networking_and_communications_7.html

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("index.xml");
var fileRef:FileReference = new FileReference();
fileRef.download(request);
```